# Delete multiple file types within mounted disk

Tags: bash

So I'm trying to write a bash script which simply deletes unwanted files from a selected drive and go in and delete files within subdirectories of that drive.

How should I write the find lines in order for the script to execute and do what is needed? Additionally how can one combine 'find' lines into one line? Do you simply just add && and repeat the line?

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR=/mnt/01d0d00dd0d00d/folder1
#ROOT_UID=0

#check for root
if [[ root == "$(whoami)" ]] || { echo "Please run as root."; exit 1; } 

else
echo "init cleanup of dirs"
echo ""
#delete files within subdirectories 
echo "Deleting .txt, .jpg and .nfo files"
find $DIR -xdev '(' -name "*.txt" -o -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.nfo" ')' -type f -delete
echo ""
echo "Cleanup completed."
# Deleted files .nfo, .txt, , .jpg" 
#echo out which type of files that was found and removed
fi
```

Comment: **Warning** - while this is a normal use of the shell, it can be horribly dangerous for the inexperienced. One wrong pattern passed to `find`, one inadvertent `PATH` beginning above wanted files -- and you better have backups. An additional safeguard you may want to consider is creating a separate directory structure mirroring the `PATH` given to `find` and move (`mv`) the files to be deleted to the mirrored path for review before actual deletion. Validate any deletion script **thoroughly** before turning them loose on your actual drive `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Use `-delete` with `find` to operate on the selected files.

```
find $DIR -xdev '(' -name "*.txt" -o -name "*.jpg" ')' -type f -delete
```

Will remove all the file under `DIR`. use `-o` flag to find both `txt` and `jpg`

Comment: `-xdev` is useful to avoid scanning other "drives" mounted under `$DIR`

Comment: `-delete` is better than `-exec rm`.

Comment: This helped me. Also would like input on the correct way to check if user is root.

Comment: `[[ root == "$(whoami)" ]] || { echo "Please run as root."; exit 1; }`